# Why isn't my paragraph aligning to the left?

Tags: html, css

I want the paragraph to be aligned to the left

Is there something wrong with my HTML or my CSS?

```
<ul class="imp">
    <h2 <li>Born: August 11, 1967 (age 53 years), Newark, New Jersey, United States </li> </h2>
    <h2 <li>Height: 1.71 m </li></h2>
    <h2 <li>Children: 2 </li></h2>
    <h2 <li>Spouse: Jessica Ditzel (m. 2009)</li></h2>
<ul/>

<div>
    <p><h2>He has also worked as a television host and an actor. Rogan began his career in comedy in August 1988 in the Boston area. After relocating to Los Angeles in 1994, he signed an exclusive developmental deal with Disney, and appeared as an actor on several television shows including Hardball and NewsRadio. In 1997, he started working for the Ultimate Fighting Championship (UFC) as an interviewer and color commentator. Rogan released his first comedy special in 2000. From 2001 to 2006, he was the host of Fear Factor. In 2009, Rogan launched his podcast The Joe Rogan Experience, which led him to "fame, wealth and podcast superstardom".</h2></p>
</div>
```

CSS Code:

```
.imp {
    padding: 0px;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 900;
}
.para {
    padding: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 900;
}
```

Comment: paragraphs cannot contain headings, it's invalid HTML

Comment: Also there is no class of `para` in your HTML

Comment: .. **and** `ul` can only have `li` as direct childrem...so your HTML is fundamentally flawed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should is a comment, but I saw you are a newbie, so I would like to answer for more details.

- Text align left as default
- If you use list `ul`, `li` should direct children not other tags.
- `<p>` should not wrap heading `h2`.
- Class in CSS should apply to HTML by `<tagname class="class-name">...</tagname>`

Basically, your HTML wrong, not CSS.

Comment: Thanks a lot haha, spent a lot of time trying to figure out what was wrong